# Whats wrong with my Matrix Rotation?

Tags: java, matrix, geometry

I'm trying to rotate a model by

```
(float) Math.atan2(-camX.getXf() * padX, -camDir.getZf() * padY)
```

Y

and

```
-MathUtils.HALF_PI
```

Z

But

```
model.setRotation(new Matrix3(1,0,0,
                              0,(float) Math.atan2(-camX.getXf() * padX, -camDir.getZf() * padY),0,
                              0,0,-MathUtils.HALF_PI));
```

It rotates on the y axis (Though it's sideways because it's a md2 model) but rotating the Z axis doesn't make it right side up. Any idea why?

Each variable is in it's respective area of the matrix.

EDIT: alright, now I'm using this code:

```
float x = 0;
            float y = (float) Math.atan2(-camX.getXf() * padX, -camDir.getZf() * padY);
            float z = (float) -MathUtils.HALF_PI;

            float a = (float) Math.sin(x);
            float A = (float) Math.cos(x);
            float b = (float) Math.sin(y);
            float B = (float) Math.cos(y);
            float c = (float) Math.sin(z);
            float C = (float) Math.cos(z);

            Matrix3 m = new Matrix3(A*b, -(B*a),b,
                                   (C*a)+(A*b*c), (A*C)-(a*b*c), -(B*c),
                                   (a*c)-(A*C*b), (A*c)+(C*a*b), B*C);
```

But now none of the axis are rotating correctly.

This is how the matrix is set up:

```
xx, xy, xz, 
yx, yy, yz, 
zx, zy, zz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rotation matrices don't work this way. Angles don't go into matrices! Instead I assume that Java handles a rotation matrix just like any other transformation matrix in cartesian coordinates. Since I think you don't want to input the rotation matrix by hand, you are probably better off starting with a new Matrix3 (I hope it is automatically initialized at the identity matrix), and then successively rotating it using rotateX(float x), rotateY(float y) and rotateZ(float z), where x, y, z are the angles you want to rotate about. (In case you are using com.threed.jpct.Matrix, at least.) Note that the result does depend on the succession of the three rotations.

Comment: I'm not using com.threed.jpct.Matrix :(
Any idea how I use two Cartesian coordinates to rotate one axis? I.E. using x and y. I can only rotate by one axis at a time without using a matrix and it resets the other axises to 0.

Comment: What are you using then? You could go the brute-force way: Let a = sin x, A = cos x, b = sin y, B = cos y, c = sin z, C = cos z. Then, try the matrix { ( AB, -Ba, b ), ( Ca+Abc, AC-abc, -Bc ), ( ac-ACb, Ac+Cab, BC ) }. That's if my calculations are right. It should correspond to rotateX about x then rotateY about y then rotateZ about z.

Comment: Oh, and also you can use matMul to multiply matrices. So you take an identity matrix and rotateX it, then take an identity matrix and rotateY it, then take an identity matrix and rotateZ it, and matMul them togehter.

Comment: Alright, can you check the edit of my question and see if I did everything right?

Comment: I'm using Ardor3d so I can't use rotateX and rotateY :(

Comment: I have no idea about Ardor3d's libraries - there doesn't seem to be a documentation online. Note that I assume that the rotations are in order x-first, y-second, z-third. Dunno which one you want.

Comment: Alright, I edited my question to show how the matrix is set up. I am trying to rotate the Y and Z axis.

Comment: Since you are not using the x-axis, you can set a = 0 and A = 1, which simplifies my matrix quite a bit. Anyway, as I said, I don't have the library here to test stuff and I never have worked with ardor3d; try some easy cases (for example x=y=0) and look what is going wrong. For example, I can imagine that it does the rotation "the wrong way round", in which case you should put a = sin (-x) etc rather than a = sin x etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a typical tutorial on how to use rotation matrices http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/matrix/orthogonal/rotation/index.htm. The order of applying rotations round the three axes is critical. Alternatively you can rotate about an arbitrary axis. Also you may want to explore [quaternions](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/32class/Quaternion.java.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is what a rotation matrix looks like in 2D; it rotates a point in (x,y) space about the z-axis in the counterclockwise direction.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix